# How should I format output for reading into a list of vectors

Tags: r, input, formatting

I have a program that outputs to file an unevenly spaced time series of vectors (one vector per interval) that vary in size . I'm wondering what would be the best way of formatting the output so that the file can be read into a list of vectors in R (Assuming that is the correct data structure), and what code in R i would use to read it.

For example, I imagine the output could look something like this:

```
1, 24, 5, 211
3, 5
59, 465, 3, 333, 9, 98
```

or

```
(1 24 5 211)
(3 5)
(59 465 3 333 9 98)
```

But what I'm saying is that I want to change the formatting to suite the R read function.

Comment: How are you producing that file? Can you give an example of how it looks right now?

Comment: @nicola Well I could make it look any way that's convenient is what I'm saying. I'm sort of assuming each vector will be written to its owns line (row) though.

Comment: You just use `readLines` and then split with the comma separator (for the first format): `x<-readLines("path/to/file");lapply(strsplit(x,", *"),as.numeric)` and you get a list of vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Keep `fill = TRUE`

```
data = read.table(file.choose(),sep=",",fill=TRUE)

data[is.na(data)] <- ""   # Replacing NA Values with nothing..
```